# Absorbing Markov chain but the absorbing states don't absorb right away

Tags: statistics, reference-request, markov-chains

What's the name of a Markov chain where there are states which absorb if they return to themselves twice in a row?

Say I have $5$ states, and state $5$ absorbs if it gets hit twice in a row.

For example, the sequence $1\rightarrow 5\rightarrow 3\rightarrow \cdots$ is possible but if we have $1\rightarrow 3\rightarrow 5\rightarrow 5 \rightarrow \cdots$ then all subsequent states are necessarily $5$.

I've seen some rough work with these where it seems that some sort of "exit matrix" is subtracted from the transition matrix in order to calculate average number of steps and whatnot but I can't find any information about these particular kinds of Markov chains as I don't know what they're called.

Comment: I would try to augment the chain to call the second visit to state 5 a separate state, call it 5', of which is absorbing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not a Markov chain. In a Markov chain, by definition the probability of transitioning from $5$ to $3$ or to $5$ is independent of the earlier history of the process and is entirely determined by the current state $5$.

As suggested in a comment, to model this behaviour with a Markov chain you can introduce a separate absorbing state $5'$ and have $5$ transition to that instead of to itself.

Comment: Is there some other kind of stochastic process that can be used to model this?

Comment: @IAlreadyHaveAKey: There may be; I don't know what it is you're modeling. But why do you want another process to model it when we've just described how you can fix your Markov chain to model it?

Comment: @IAlreadyHaveAKey second-order Markov chain.

Comment: @joriki: for the sake of expanding my knowledge of stochastic processes more than anything.